# Map zooming out automatically

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a map based application to find out nearby places (like Restaurants, Hospitals, etc) around user's current location. When suppose I click on restaurants, it loads nearby restaurants around users current location correctly in the Google Map. But when I zoom in 2-3 or more times on the map to click on my required marker, it zooms out automatically in some time. I just want to have control in that zoom out event. What can I do to avoid the automatic zooming out thing in map?

Thanks in advance!!

The below class displays the markers and infowindow in the map.

```
public class PlacesDisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    JSONObject googlePlacesJson;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private int grpId;
    private String name;
    Context mContext;
    private Location location;
    Map<LatLng, String> vicinities = new HashMap<LatLng, String>();
    ImageView iv;
    //Context getContext;

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Object... inputObj) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> googlePlacesList = null;
        Places placeJsonParser = new Places();

        try {
            googleMap = (GoogleMap) inputObj[0];
            grpId = (Integer)inputObj[2];
            mContext = (Context)inputObj[3];
            location = (Location)inputObj[4];
            name = (String)inputObj[5];
            googlePlacesJson = new JSONObject((String) inputObj[1]);
            googlePlacesList = placeJsonParser.parse(googlePlacesJson);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return googlePlacesList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        googleMap.clear();
        if (list==null){
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            final HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = list.get(i);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
            final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            final BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getIcon(grpId));
            final String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
            vicinities.put(latLng, vicinity);

            markerOptions.position(latLng)
                            .title(placeName)
                    .icon(icon);

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

                    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv1);

                    tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_info);
                    return v;
                }
            });

            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AddressGenerator.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    intent.putExtra("place_value", marker.getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("vicinity_value", vicinities.get(marker.getPosition()));
                    intent.putExtra("lat_dest", String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude));
                    intent.putExtra("lng_dest",String.valueOf( marker.getPosition().longitude));
                    intent.putExtra("lat_src", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                    intent.putExtra("lng_src", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private int getIcon(int groupId){

        int icon = 0;
        switch (groupId){
            case 0:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_personal_care;
                break;
            case 1:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_atm;
                break;
            case 2:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_shopping;
                break;
            case 3:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_health;
                break;
            case 4:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_indicator;
                break;
            case 5:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_petrol;
                break;
            case 6:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_entertainment;
                break;
            case 7:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_bar;
                break;
            case 8:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_service_station;
                break;
            case 9:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_police;
                break;
            case 10:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_food;
                break;
            case 11:
                icon = R.drawable.rsz_worship;
                break;
        }
        return icon;
    }
}
```

### MapsActivity.class

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000;
private String type;
private int grpId;
private String name;
private final static int REQUEST_CODE_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private final static int REQUEST_CODE_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyBEZMt******Jhvct-OXni8mX*******w7GX4Q";
private View view;
LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    view = findViewById(R.id.map_id);
    if(checkPermission()){
     //   Snackbar.make(view, "Permission already granted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        requestPermission();
    }
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }

    type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    grpId = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("grpId"));
    name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

    googleMap = ((MapFragment) (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // getting GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // getting network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
    {
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    else {

        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, locationListener);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, this);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if (googleMap != null) {
        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);

        GooglePlacesReadTask googlePlacesReadTask = new GooglePlacesReadTask();
        Object[] toPass = new Object[6];
        toPass[0] = googleMap;
        toPass[1] = googlePlacesUrl.toString();
        toPass[2] = grpId;
        toPass[3] = getApplicationContext();
        toPass[4] = location;
        toPass[5] = name;
        googlePlacesReadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, toPass);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see the code above. Thanx!

Comment: How are you initializing your map?

Comment: By passing intent from my home activity to map activity class.  Intent mapIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

Comment: @antonio: I hav updated the MapsActivity.class too.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving (and animating) the camera each time the `onLocationChanged`is called.

As you are doing:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
```

The second line overrides the first one and the effect is that the map is zoomed.

Just remove these lines to avoid the zooming effect.

Comment: If I remove these two lines, the map wont zoom at all to the current location. It will just show the world map. And zooming in is not an issue. Zooming out is the problem. It zooms out automatically after some time of zooming in.